# Export attributes of shapefiles into text file

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm trying to export attributes of multiple shapefiles a text file. I am multiple getting errors when I run my code not sure what the issue is.  Any direction as to where to start to fix this would be helpful.

> File "C:\users\Export.py", line 7, in 
>       fclist = arcpy.ListFields(table)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy__init__.py", line 1119, in
>   ListFields
>       return gp.listFields(dataset, wild_card, field_type)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   344, in listFields
>       self._gp.ListFields(*gp_fixargs(args, True))) RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.

Heres my code: 
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\user\\rainfiles"
table = "C:\\user\\rain_files"
outWorkspace = "C:\\user"
fclist = arcpy.ListFields(table)
field_names = [field.name for field in fclist] 
for field in fclist:
    with open(r'C:\\user\\Exports.txt', 'w') as f:
        for field in fclist:
            f.write(field + '\n')
with open(r'C:\\user\\Exports.txt', 'r') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f) 
    w.writerow(field_names)            
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(table):  
        field_vals = [row.getValue(field.name) for field in fclist]  
        w.writerow(field_vals)
    del row
```

Comment: is "C:\\user\\rain_files" a coverage? if not, table is a folder and doesn't have fields to list, you will probably need to do something like for ThisFC in arcpy.ListDatasets(): to supply the dataset to list the fields from.

Comment: In reading the exception messages from top to bottom, you'll see `ListFields` isn't happy. At the bottom is the exception type, an `IOError` would imply the data doesn't exist, a `RuntimeError` like you have, suggests it's not a valid data source (I'd guess `table` is a folder).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, `ListFields` on an invalid data source is the probable cause. There are several other issues that are going to trip you up once you solve that though. I took a rough pass at the code

```
import arcpy
import csv

table = r'your_input'
output = r'your_output'

fields = arcpy.ListFields(table)
field_names = [field.name for field in fields if field.type != 'Geometry'] 

with open(output, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f) 
    w.writerow(field_names)            
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(table):  
        field_vals = [row.getValue(field) for field in field_names]  
        w.writerow(field_vals)
    del row
```

If you're using at least 10.1, you'd be better off using `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`.

```
import arcpy
import csv

table = r'your_input'
output = r'your_output'

fields = arcpy.ListFields(table)
field_names = [field.name for field in fields if field.type != 'Geometry'] 

with open(output, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f) 
    w.writerow(field_names)            
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, field_names) as cursor:  
        for row in cursor:
            w.writerow(row)
```